# Doctrine's ProxyCacheWarmer: "Unable to create the Doctrine Proxy directory"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can't seem to find information about this issue so I decided to post it.

Production crashes sometimes with
`Doctrine's ProxyCacheWarmer: "Unable to create the Doctrine Proxy directory"`

However the app seems to be working just fine.

Is there any points on what is happening, and why things to be functioning despiste this issue?

Comment: I have same error. You need execute update packages: `composer update` or update only doctrine packages: `composer update --with-dependencies doctrine/*`